# How to interpret individual characters received from command arguments in C?

Tags: c, command, arguments

Im new, please be Gentle.
i am trying to write a program that takes input from command arguments (such as 3+3 or 4/3 or 4*3) then does a calculation based off of the middle character (operator?). Here is what i have so far any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float numberOne;
float numberTwo;
float theResult;
char action;

if (argc == 3)
{
    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &action);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%f", &numberTwo);

    switch (action)
    {
    case + :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne + numberTwo);
        break;
    case - :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne - numberTwo);
        break;
    case * :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne * numberTwo);
        break;
    case / :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne / numberTwo);
        break;
    }

}
else
{
    printf("invalid input");
}

sleep(10);
return(0);

}
```

Comment: The command line arguments will need to be space-separated, so `3 + 3` not `3+3`. Also change `if (argc == 3)` to `if (argc == 4)`, because `argv[0]` is typically the executable's name. Finally watch out for "divide by 0" errors (more of a problem if you were using integer types).

Comment: Also Command line `*` may need to be escaped.

Comment: You apparently know that string literals uses double quotes, but seem to have forgotten that character literals uses single quotes `'`. Unless you ask about build errors, then make sure that your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) actually *builds*. And *if* you ask about build-errors, then explicitly say so, and include the errors you get (in full, complete, copy-pasted as text).